# Mongoid + Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, cucumber, mongoid

I try to run a scenario with Cucumber, through Capybara, in a Rails 3.2.3 app supported by Mongoid. The aim is to have current user add a book to his collection.

Everything goes ok, but the final step definition, where I check that the amount of books is now one, fails.

But if I check on the app controller, the size actually increased. And actually, when I send `reload` to the user in the step definition, it passes:

```
user.reload.books(true).size.should == 1
```

I'm afraid this behavior could harm my app once in production. Any advice how to make sure all tests and app behaviors are consistent?

**UPDATE**

I checked the test.log to see what's going on.
Calling `reload` I get this query to MongoDB:

```
find({"count"=>"books",
"query"=>{:_id=>{"$in"=>[BSON::ObjectId('4f889b473dffd63235000004')]}},
"fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
```

while without the reload I get this:

```
find({"count"=>"books", "query"=>{:_id=>{"$in"=>[]}}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
```

It practically doesn't query against the `user` if I don't reload the model, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

### The following works for me (updated with actual Cucumber example)

I built a Rails project to test out your issue, rails 3.2.3, mongoid 2.4.8, mongo 1.6.2, mongodb 2.0.4, cucumber 1.1.9.

The following (association generated methods) work as expected, without need for refresh:

```
user.books << book
book.users << user
```

Then I tried to bypass the association, which was what I thought that you were doing.

```
user.push(:book_ids, book.id)
book.push(:user_ids, user.id)
```

These DO bypass the association, resulting in incomplete (one-way instead of two-way) references, but the memory and db state is consistent. So my guess in my previous answer about what you were experiencing was wrong, there's no refresh needed and you are probably doing something else. Note that you/we do not want the incomplete references, please do not push directly to the internals for Mongoid referenced relations.

Are you using the association append "<<" for adding a user or a book? My current conclusion is that Mongoid referenced relations work as advertized for my test of your issue. There's no need for refresh.

Here's the model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :author, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Cucumber feature

```
Feature: UserAndBook
  Test adding a book to a user_s books

  Scenario: add_book_to_user
    Given starting with no users and no books
    And a new user
    And that the new user has no books
    And a new book
    And add book to user
    Then I can check that the user has a book
```

Cucumber steps

```
require 'test/unit/assertions'
require File.expand_path('../../../test/test_helper', __FILE__)
World(Test::Unit::Assertions)

Given 'starting with no users and no books' do
  User.delete_all
  Book.delete_all
  assert_equal(0, User.count)
  assert_equal(0, Book.count)
end

Given 'a new user' do
  @user = User.create(first_name: 'Gary', last_name: 'Murakami')
end

Given 'that the new user has no books' do
  assert_equal(0, @user.books.count)
end

Given 'a new book' do
  @book = Book.create(title: 'A Tale of Two Cities', author: 'Charles Dickens')
end

Given 'add book to user' do
  @user.books << @book
end

Then 'I can check that the user has a book' do
  assert_equal(1, @user.books.count)
end
```

I'm open to further exchange of info to help to address your issue.

Blessings,

-Gary

P.S. Looking at the log, it is interesting to see that user.books.length does an actual db "find count $in" query rather than a local array length.

### Previous answer

You've pretty much answered your own question. In Rails, you need to use the reload method whenever data for your model has changed in the database, otherwise you will just be looking at the previously loaded/instantiated/cached state of your model.  With update of just an attribute, things look pretty consistent, but associations are more complicated and the inconsistency becomes more obvious.

Comment: I have made several apps with Cucumber and ActiveRecord/MySQL and I never had this kind of inconsistencies, requiring me to force reload of my models. There is something about Mongoid/MongoDB that eludes me.

Comment: How did you specify the relation between user and books?  Are the books embedded or in a separate collection? How did you add the book to the users collection?

Comment: Edited answer with results of a Rails/Mongoid projects that I think works the way you want.

Comment: I've added some logging from the tests to try and understand what's happening there.

Comment: I've updated my answer with actual Cucumber feature and steps that work for me, hope that it works for you and that you can make progress.